# How to display name using asterisks pattern in java

Tags: java

I want to display my letters using asterisks and wish they can be side by side.

```
system.out.println("Enter Message:"); 
        String message = msg.nextLine();   


        int n=message.length();
        char msgList[]= new char[n];

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            msgList[i]= message.charAt(i);
        }
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            switch (msgList[j]) {
                case 'A':
                    A picA = new A();
                    break;
                case 'B':
                    B picB = new B();
                    break;
                case 'C':
                    C picC = new C();
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    D picD = new D();
                    break;
                case 'E':
                    E picE = new E();
                    break;
                ....

            }
```

Comment: Your question seems to have nothing to do with design patterns, so I have removed that tag.

Comment: Im good with the pattern part, it just that the letter print out vertically, any idea on how to print them out horizontally.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the letter to print out next to the `"Enter Message:"` text? If so, just use `System.out.print("Enter Message:");`.